# "description" fails for NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a class that is derived from NSURLConnection.  Curiously, `description` and `dealloc` fail when directed to the NSURLConnection (even though the actual data transfer operation succeeds).

Here is the `init` method of my class:

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"%s -- self description is %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [self description]);
    NSLog(@"%s -- super description is %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [super description]);
    return self;
}
```

Here is the log output from executing this code (I implemented `description` for my class):

```
2011-08-24 10:41:40.493 SleepyHead[77578:207] -[BinaryExchange init] -- self description is <BinaryExchange>
(gdb) continue
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

When this happens the debugger is stopped on the `[super description]` line, and in the call to `NSURLConnection description`.

What the heck is going on?

(I tried allocating and *not* initing another copy of the class before this one, on the off-chance that there was a piece of bogus heap getting used, but I still get the same failure.)

### Added:

Even this sequence fails:

```
NSURLConnection* dummy = [[NSURLConnection alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%s -- dummy NSURLConnection description is %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [dummy description]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a crash, there is a backtrace.  Post it.

Odd crash, though.

`[super description]` is pretty close to nonsense.  The `description` method is not intended to ever be used in a production environment;  is a development-only method.

Did you override `description` in your subclass, perchance?

Also *allocating and not initing another* doesn't really do anything.  It may not even allocate anything.  Most class clusters and many other classes (as implementation details) will return a singleton on `alloc` and it isn't until the initialization that a particular subclass is instantiated.

---

Oh -- `NSURLConnection` doesn't use `init` as the designated initializer.  It needs a request.  More likely than not, by calling `init`, you aren't actually initializing the class and it crashes rather spectacularly as a result of undefined internal state.

Use `initWithRequest:....`

Comment: No backtrace in the log.  But the debugger is open and the sequence is [myclass init] -> [NSURLConnection description].  `description` is being used to debug, and, as I stated, I overrode `description` in my class, because I was attempting to figure out this problem.  (The same failure occurs, as I stated with [myclass dealloc] -> [NSURLConnection dealloc], and that's the problem I started out debugging.)

Comment: OK, that I can believe -- this code is a hack from some other (of course).  I'll look into it.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see anywhere where it says you *can't* use `init` (and the docs generally don't list valid inherited methods, including init methods).  But I'll look into it more.

Comment: OK, that was amazingly simple, once one's looking in the right forest.  Making the superclass NSObject seems to work just fine -- the NSURLConnection was probably a dupe error of some sort.

Comment: (It would be nice if this sort of stuff was documented, though.)

Comment: Agreed;  if `init` doesn't work on `NSURLConnection`, it should barf appropriately.   Please file a bug.